# Elegant way to init multiple variables in Javascript

Tags: javascript, optimization, initialization

I have a function to set visibility of multiple elements depending on a type of element user chose.

```
  function setVisibility(type) {
    switch (type) {
      case 'A':
        ctrl.show.1 = true;
        ctrl.show.2 = true;
        ctrl.show.3 = true;
        ...
        break;
      case 'B':
        ctrl.show.1 = true;
        ctrl.show.3 = true;
        ctrl.show.5 = true;
        ...
        break;
      case 'C':
        ctrl.show.2 = true;
        ctrl.show.4 = true;
        ctrl.show.6 = true;
         ...
        break;
      case 'D':
      ...
      default:
        break;
    }
```

Each case has different elements and some of them are shared between them. I thought to change the switch with an object, like:

```
function setVisibility(type) {
 let cases = {
   A = initA,
   B = initB,
   ...
 };
  cases[type]();
}
function initA(){
  ctrl.show = {
    1 : true,
    2 : true,
    3 : true,
     ...
    };
}
```

But my question is, is there a better way to init multiple values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an object of arrays to configure which elements to display

```
var cases = {
    A: [1, 2, 3],
    // ...
};
```

Then iterate over the cases array to set the value to true

```
for (var i in cases[type]) {
    ctrl.show[cases[type][i]] = true;
}
```

Comment: I wrote it in ES2015, and for bucle results in:
`for (let i of cases[type]) {  ctrl.show[i] = true; } `
And it works as expected.